# Is $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = L$ same thing as f continuous at c?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I know the two definitions for continuity, (sequential and epsilon-delta)

Given $x_0 \in D, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, |x - x_0| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon $

and

f is continuous if $\forall x_n \rightarrow x_0 $ implies $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$

Now the definition of $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = L$ is $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 |x - x_0| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$

So are the two $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions the same? ie $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = L$ implies $f$ is continuous at $x_0$? I want to make sure.

Comment: If you assume that $x_0$ is in the domain of definition of $f$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371922/limits-why-fx-can-be-equal-to-l-and-x-cant-be-equal-to-c/3371938#3371938) relatively recently about this.

Comment: That is *not* the definition for $\lim_{x\mapsto x_0} f(x) = L$. It should read $0 < |x-x_0|<\delta$. And that's kind of the point here.

Comment: People, some of the answers and comments here are confusing. Please check with the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\1 \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}$. For $x_0 := 0$, obviously $x_0 \in D$, obviously $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$, obviously $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = 0$, although with the wrong definition in the OP, $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$ implies $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ **if and only if** $L=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Since $x_0\in D$, it follows from $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L$ that $L = f(x_0)$.

Comment: oops. I think I get the point though. $f$ would be continuous if $x_0 \in D$, this additional condition was satisfied.

Comment: @amsmath: That would follow only from the wrong definition of $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L$ used in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You are given that
$$
\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists\delta>0 : |x-x_0|<\delta\,\Longrightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.
$$
For any $\epsilon>0$ you can thus choose $x=x_0$ (because $|x-x_0|=0$) to get $|f(x_0)-L|<\epsilon$ and thus $f(x_0) = L$. Hence, you can replace $L$ above by $f(x_0)$ to see that $f$ is indeed continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Oh ok, and to make that replacement we need to ensure $L = f(x_0)$ is true, or $x_0 \in D$

Comment: Without $x_0\in D$ we cannot talk about continuity at $x_0$ anyways. So, we should assume that.

Comment: In a correct definition of a limit, one is precisely not allowed to set $x=x_0$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg You're right. I just took the definition of OP. The usual one excludes $x_0$.

Comment: mind enlightening me on the proper def of limit? I googled this..

Comment: @MinYoungKim In the definition you will find $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$.