# About the definition for limit in "Introduction to Analysis I" (in Japanese) by Mitsuo Sugiura.

Tags: limits, analysis, definition

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis I" (in Japanese) by Mitsuo Sugiura.

This book is the standard and the most popular introductory analysis book in Japan.

---

The standard definition for limit:
Let $f$ be a function from $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $a\in\overline{A},b\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
We write $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$$ if for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $$0<|x-a|<\delta\text{  and  }x\in A\implies |f(x)-b|<\varepsilon.$$

---

Definition for limit in this book:
Let $f$ be a function from $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $a\in\overline{A},b\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
We write $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$$ if for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $$|x-a|<\delta\text{  and  }x\in A\implies |f(x)-b|<\varepsilon.$$

---

Definition 2 for limit in this book:
Let $f$ be a function from $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
Let $B\subset A$ and $a\in\overline{B}$.
We write $$\lim_{x\to a\\x\in B}f(x)=b$$ if for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $$|x-a|<\delta\text{  and  }x\in B\implies |f(x)-b|<\varepsilon.$$

---

Let $f$ be a function from $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
Let $a\in A$ and $B:=\{x\in A\mid x\neq a\}$ and $a\in\overline{B}$.
Then $$\lim_{x\to a\\x\in B} f(x)=b$$ is equivalent to the standard definition for limit.

---

I think the definition for limit in this book is not standard.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this definition for limit?

Are there any other books which adopt this definition for limit?

Comment: Where you’ve written, $|x - a| < \delta$ in both definitions, did you mean to write $0 < |x - a| < \delta$? As written, the definitions characterise continuity of $f$ at $a$ (in the latter case, $f$ restricted to $B$), and $b = f(a)$. Without this change, I would definitely say the definitions are non-standard, and possibly even (dare I say it) outright wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I am overlooking something.  The only tangible difference that I see is that in the first two definitions in your posting, the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ portion is missing:  $$\color{red}{0 < } |x - a| < \delta \cdots .$$

Comment: Theo Bendit, user2661923, Thank you very much for your comments. The author wrote $|x-a|<\delta$. The author didn't write $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Comment: I don't understand what you have written in this question very well. There are two "Definition for limit" and then something which I cannot make head or tail of given as "the standard definition for limit".

Comment: Why do we care whether $|x-a|=0$?

Comment: @SuzuHirose https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371922/limits-why-fx-can-be-equal-to-l-and-x-cant-be-equal-to-c/3371938#3371938

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you, learning so much here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limits: why $f(x)$ can be equal to $L$ and $x$ can't be equal to $c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371922/limits-why-fx-can-be-equal-to-l-and-x-cant-be-equal-to-c) Given how you’ve edited your question, I would basically just be restating what I said in response to this question.